# Does using Bots in WoW Break the ToS?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, legal

Does using bots in WoW break the Terms of Service if you are indeed present of the computer and chatting away like nothing is happening? I say this because I notice who are just doing the EXACT same process in BGs ( I.E Running into walls all the time ) Yet are raging on /i that we are loosing etc. So basically am asking , does it comes down to ethics to bot or is it highly illegal & break the ToS?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Been a while I've played WoW but it was happening to me to run into walls while typing... just don't assume they are bots :)

Comment: Yes. Target them, right click and Report Cheating.

Comment: There is an auto run feature that allows the character to continue running without any further user input, if someone is at their keyboard they aren't likely to be a bot, it would be a waste of time to report them as such. if you see a player doing the same thing over and over without interacting with environment at all they are likely to be a bot, this is particularly common in battlegrounds at certain times of day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

From the [TOS](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/wow_tou.html):

> You agree that you will not, under any circumstances:
>
> A. use cheats, **automation software (bots)**, hacks, mods or any other unauthorized third-party software designed to modify the World of Warcraft experience;

Comment: Perfect answer good sir! I thought it was along these lines but couldn't find the exact words in my ToS. +1 And Answer